# Django create POST intermediate model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRM v3.9.4 and have the following models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   ...
   users = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="books", through="BookUser")

class BookUser(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   book = models.ForeignKey("Book", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   permission = models.CharField(...)

class User(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   ...
```

with the following serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( "id", ... )

class BookUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BookUser
        fields = ('user', 'permission')

class BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    users = BookUserSerializer(source='bookuser_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ( "id", "users", ... )
        extra_kwargs = {
            "users": {"allow_empty": True},
        }
```

When reading (GET) a Book everything is fine:

```
{
   id: ...,
   users: [
       {
           user: 'some-uuid',
           permission: 'read-only'
       },
       ...
   ]
}
```

but when trying to POST using the same payload:

```
{
   id: ...,
   users: [
       {
           user: 'some-uuid',
           permission: 'read-only'
       },
       ...
   ]
}
```

I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'users'
```

looking at the api-guide (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)
seems that by default nested serializers are read-only,
but I can't make it work.

BTW, IMPORTANT: all the users are (and should) already exist, so I expect this POST call to add a record in the intermediate `BookUser` table, and ofcourse the `Book` itself, but NOT to actually add new User(s) records.

Any help, guiding or assistance would be appreciate as how to make this thing work

Answer (score 0):

Using `drf-writable-nested` package you can achieve that:

```
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class BookSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    users = BookUserSerializer(source='bookuser_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Book
       fields = ( "id", "users", ... )
       extra_kwargs = {
          "users": {"allow_empty": True},
       }
```

[DRF Writable nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested)